# Trying to create a child element in Xml serialization, doesn't show up

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to generate the following XML, and this is also the first time that I ever serialize XML. Could anyone explain to me why my `<issuer>` element isn't showing up?

**What is generated:**

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="02279359-0581-41c7-a66b-199523ac8eab" IssueInstant="18:07:2014 10:41:37 AM" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" />
```

**What I need generated:**

```
<samlp:Response ID="02279359-0581-41c7-a66b-199523ac8eab" IssueInstant="18:07:2014 10:41:37 AM" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.partner.com/sso</saml:Issuer>
</samlp:Response>
```

What I don't understand is that I marked the Issuer as an XMLElement.

Here is my code.

**MySaml.cs**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol", IsNullable = false)]
public class MySaml
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Version")]
    public const string Version = "2.0";

    [XmlAttribute("IssueInstant")]
    public string IssueInstant { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Destination")]
    public const string Destination = "https://www.site.com/SC/SSO/SingleSignOn.aspx";

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "xmlns", AttributeName = "samlp")]
    public const string samlp = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol";

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", ElementName = "Issuer", IsNullable = false)]
    public readonly Issuer Issuer = new Issuer();

}
```

**Issuer.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class Issuer
{
    [XmlText]
    public const string Text = "https://www.partner.com/sso";

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "xmlns", AttributeName = "saml")]
    public const string saml = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";
}
```

Lastly, The methods I am trying to use to generate the SAML (and pardon the ugly string manipulation there - I am planning to bomb it)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenerateSamlAssertion();  
}

private void GenerateSamlAssertion()
{
    var response = new MySaml();
    response.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    response.IssueInstant = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

    SerializeXml(response);
}

public XmlDocument SerializeXml(MySaml mySaml)
{
    var xmlSerializerNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlSerializerNameSpace.Add("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
    xmlSerializerNameSpace.Add("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySaml));

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, mySaml, xmlSerializerNameSpace);             
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(writer.ToString().Remove(0, writer.ToString().IndexOf("\r\n") + 1));
            return doc;
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I know what I am missing must either be something stupid or something small.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be serialized, a field or property must be public, and cannot be readonly.

Here's a worked example:

```
void Main()
{
    Serialize(new ToSerialize());
    Serialize(new ToSerialize2());
}

private void Serialize(object o)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, o);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}

public class ToSerialize2
{
    public ToSerialize2()
    {
        this.Other = new Other();
    }

    public Other Other;
}

public class ToSerialize
{
    public readonly Other Other = new Other();
}

public class Other
{
}
```

The output of ToSerialzie misses the "Other" XML element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ToSerialize xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

ToSerialize2 includes it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ToSerialize2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Other />
</ToSerialize2>
```

Comment: Got that. Thanks. Just having issues with random namespaces popping up all over the show, but that's another question for another day

Comment: @a-h, I think that's just due to the `readonly` keyword, not property vs. field.